# Saving a randomly picked element in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array
`loan = %w(100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000)` I want to `.sample` this array and store it to use at a later time.

I'm creating an ATM program and am creating a class for loans..

Source:

```
require_relative 'loanamount.rb' #Where the above array is stored

private #Is part of an ATM class, which has nothing to do with this section

class Loan < ATM
    attr_accessor :credit
        def initialize( score )
            @score = 0
        end
    end

    def loan_info
        puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >Hello and welcome to the credit station
            >Please choose from the list below
            >Would you like to Apply for a loan '1'
            >Check credit score '2'
            >Go back '3'
            >
        END
        input = gets.chomp
        case input.to_i
        when 1
            apply_credit
        when 2
            check_score
        else
            redirect
        end
    end

    def apply_credit
        if @score >= 640
            accepted
        else
            denied_loan
        end
    end

    def accepted
        puts "You have been accepted for a #{loan.sample} loan which will be added to your bank account"
        puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >Which account would you like to add that to?
            >Checking Account '1'
            >Savings Account '2'
            >
        END
        input = gets.chomp
        case input.to_i
        when 1
            @checking_account += "#{loan}"#I want to add the amount that loan.sample gave
            puts "#{loan} has been added to your checking account, your new balance is #{@checking_account}"
            puts "Your card will now be returned for security purposes."
            exit
        when 2
            @savings_account += "#{loan}" #Not completed yet..
        end
    end
```

So for example:

```
loan = ["100", "200", "300"] 
puts "You are given #{loan.sample}"
puts "You now have *amount*" #I want to be able to call the amount that loan.sample gave me"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware that Ruby has very strict differences between strings and numbers. The following code will not work as expected:

```
@checking_account += "#{loan}"
```

This is trying to add a string to what is presumably a number, though I can't see where `@checking_account` is initialized.

You probably mean this:

```
loan_amount = loan.sample
@checking_account += loan_amount

puts "Your loan for %d was approved, your balance is now %d" % [
  loan_amount,
  @checking_account
]
```

This also requires that `loan` is an array of numbers:

```
loan = ["100", "200", "300"] # Incorrect, is strings
loan = [ 100, 200, 300 ] # Correct, is numbers
```

Some languages like PHP and JavaScript will automatically convert between strings and numbers as necessarily, or often arbitrarily, but Ruby does not and will complain if you try.

As a note you'll want to start using structures to organize your data better, for example:

```
@accounts = Hash.new(0)
@accounts[:checking] += loan_amount
```

Comment: I'm aware, the code would have outputted the entire array, or nothing at all. You answered my question so thank you

Comment: Hope that helps. It can be a bit confusing how Ruby is so strict about things, but you'll get the hang of it.